# Does Sprite Kit render in the background, or on the main thread? How does it work?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, opengl-es, sprite-kit

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) shows a simplified runloop of Sprite Kit.

I am trying to understand how they implemented it. A [SKView](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html) calls -update: on a [SKScene](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html). This then first evaluates actions, then simulates physics, and lets the subclass adjust the scene. After changes are made to the scene, [SKView](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html) finally renders the node tree to the screen.

What I don't understand are the fine details. Does Sprite Kit decouple scene calculations from scene rendering by using different threads or GCD queues? Does it perform all the OpenGL rendering calls in the background, or is everything happening on the main thread? At which points is Sprite Kit switching back and forth between background and main thread, and how does it sync processing the scene with rendering the scene then? What happens when your scene updates take too long?

Comment: no one besides Apple engineers has the source code, so answers to this question will largely be speculative. Besides that, it doesn't actually matter much which way they did what. If you want to learn engine design pick up a book or inspect an open source engine or two or three

Comment: Sprite Kit is only representational in this question. I want to understand how they possibly or most likely did it.

Comment: and that is speculation, and in the general sense a question answered by looking into render engine design. There's certainly no definite answer to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pie chart in the linked documentation shows the render loop for Sprite Kit. Each part of the loop is executed synchronously on the main thread. The OpenGL rendering is performed by the SKView at the end of the render loop.

Much like any render loop, if the update part takes too long, then the frame time interval is exceeded. This will result in the frame being rendered on the next vsync ie a reduction in frame rate.

The rendering itself is performed just as with GLKit: the render loop is synced to the display refresh rate using a `CADisplayLink`, with the `frameInterval` property controlling how many display refreshes there are per render loop. Once the model update is complete, the GL state is then sent to the GPU and `[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:]` is called to display the SKView renderbuffer. The loop is now complete, and won't start again until the display link fires, signalling that the previous frame was rendered and another one can be sent to the screen.

Whether or not the rendering occurs off the main thread is not documented and not possible to know, but it is only an implementation detail. If it did occur on a different thread, then the entire model tree would have to be duplicated in the render thread, or sufficient state so that one frame could be rendered, while the model is updated for the next frame. Most likely it is just synchronous on the main thread. Locking would be fairly pointless, if you are going to prevent the main thread from accessing state until you are done rendering, you might as well just do the rendering on the main thread.

Comment: Can you elaborate on vsync, and how SKView probably renders? Does it simply call OpenGL functions on the main thread or is there a point where the model (SKScene) gets passed into the background with locking mechanisms in order to render it? What I still don't get is the transition between modifying the model (SKScene) and then rendering the results in SKView, wether or not this all happens on the main thread or if SKView actually renders while the next calculations of SKScene take place simultaneously.

Comment: I added a few details about the rendering. If you are interested in how to implement your own game engine, I would suggest approaching this from a less specific focus, it is not possible to know the precise details about the internals of SpriteKit. A common approach is to move the render loop off the main thread entirely, leaving the main thread to handle device input and so on.